# How to align heading <h1> in the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to center `<h1>` or `<div class="heading">` on the page. The only solution I have found is

```
body { text-align: center; }
```

but I can't figure it out why this code doesn't work. `Display: inline-block` is used because I want the border to wrap around my .

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  text-align: right;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: please see http://www.stackoverflow/help/accepted-answer : even with 1 rep you can accept an answer by hovering beside the answer and clicking the checkmark that appears once (it turns green). You will gain 2 points in rep by accepting an answer, and a badge for the first one you accept. (when you reach 15 you can upvote also.. you'll get there yet.) Welcome to stackoverflow and happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
.heading {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

...and delete `display: inline-block` from `.heading`.  Instead, add this

```
.heading h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`.heading` is the container of your `h1`. Both are by default 100% wide. This centers the inline-block `h1` inside the full-width `.heading`

Answer (score 0):

The secret you are looking for is to use a `block`-level element, and also set a `margin: 0 auto`. This tells the block to centralise, much like a standard `text-align: center`.

```
.header {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

By default, `block`-level elements occupy 100% of the width of their container, so you might also want to specify a width for the header. Alternatively, you can have the header automatically adjust to the size of the text by adding a container div that is set as in `inline-block`, and moving the border to there:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  text-align: right;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="heading">
    <div class="heading-wrapper">
      <h1>heading</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

This way, the header will stay centralised, and have the border automatically expand correctly to accommodate the header, no matter how much text there is.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

a div displays block by default, so it's definitely important to declare if you want to display it otherwise.

However, again, as in another post i saw earlier, you have no css for the containing parent, the `header`, which would greatly assist you. You should apply any margin to be inherited to this, and there should be no need to apply a small width to your div.

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

header{margin: 0 auto;}

.navbar {
text-align: right;
background: black;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 5px;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
border: 2px solid black;
/*display: block; - even if you leave this out, it will display as block*/
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="heading">
   <h1>heading</h1>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: you should display block or else the heading appears to the left

Answer (score 0):

You can center it by using `display: flex; justify-content;` on the parent element. Here is a great resource on centering things https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  text-align: right;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>about</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>heading</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```